# difference behaviour of gdb and direct execution while trying to exploit with ROP

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering, exploit

I'm learning recently some notions on ROP.
and while doing a challenge on some websites which provided the source code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char ** argv){
    char message[20];

    if (argc != 2){
        printf ("Usage: %s <message>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    strcpy (message, argv[1]);
    printf ("Your message: %s\n", message);
    return 0;
}
```

the stack is not executable, so basically i'am trying to override the return address by the address of system libc function, aslr is not used.
I'm using the environement variable SHELL, I found the address with gdb.
the distance between the address of message and the return address is 32 byte.
so my shellcode is the following: 'a' rep32 + @ofSystem + '4byteJUNK' + @SHELL

The problem is that when i'm using this shellcode directly I get segmentation fault because system function is successfully called but not with the convenient argument "/bin/bash" which is provided by the environement varialble, it's called with another non printable string, but when I use gdb I verify that the calling conventions are respected (args are passed on stack), and the shell is called successfully with the apropiate string "/bin/bash".
I couldn't find a way to check the source of the problem because the behaviour on gdb and without gdb is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that when i'm using this shellcode directly I get segmentation fault because system function is successfully called but not with the convenient argument "/bin/bash"...
>
> I couldn't find a way to check the source of the problem because the behaviour on gdb and without gdb is not the same.

There are possibly many small differences between running the program inside and outside GDB.

For example, GDB tends to invoke the program via full path, that is:

```
gdb a.out
(gdb) run
... invokes /full/path/to/a.out
```

The environment, such as `$_` could also be different.

You'll need to get a bit more creative to solve your problem. You could try to minimize the differences (e.g. use `/full/path/to/a.out` when invoking the program outside GDB), or enable `core` dump, and spelunk in the core that will be generated outside of GDB, so you can understand where things differ (and also find the distance you have found under GDB -- it's likely to be changed when running outside GDB).